# How to get original name of the image?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Hello guys How to get the original client name of an image in the collection?

I have this new code to upload more than three images

```
public function store(){

        $action = '';

        $data =  $this->validate([
            'album_title' => 'required',
            'photos.*' => 'image|max:2000', // 2MB Max
        ]);

        //New Code with collections
        $filenames = collect($this->photos)->map->store('photos');

        if($this->galleryId){
            Gallery::find($this->galleryId)->update($data);
            $action = 'edit';
        }else{
            // Gallery::create($data);
            Gallery::create([
                'album_title' => $this->album_title,
                'photos' => $filenames->implode(','),
              ]);
            $action = 'store';
        }
        $this->emit('showEmitedFlashMessage', $action);
        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->emit('refreshParent');
        $this->emit('closeGalleryModal');

    }
```

but it save something like this

```
photos/xTNV0cQ7YzpyUsJ6OdrpQirwfCPdzDtKJAKoWUFm.jpg,photos/32PkRR9bFhM7BqAy9OWG05m5fe53PUXtidEMhlnn.jpg,photos/Dyps8wCsga0zdALGsKEOS9jcYSNshnixw4UWzhEL.jpg
```

What I want is to save the original name of the images.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is set the file name to a uuid for storage in the system, but retain the original filename in the database so that you can rename it for downloads if you want. To get the original file name, you need to look at the post data for that.

like so:

```php
$this->active_document->original_filename = $this->uploaded_file->getClientOriginalName();
```

More info here in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads